# How to use boost::thread mutex to synchronize write access?

Tags: multithreading, mutex, boost-thread

I have a newbie question about `Boost::Thread` and `Mutex`.

I would like to start many parallel instances of the following `Worker`, and all of them write to the same `std::vector`:

```
struct Worker {
  std::vector<double>* vec;
  Worker(std::vector<double>* v) : vec(v) {}
  void operator() {
    // do some long computation and then add results to *vec, e.g.
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < vec->size(); ++i) {
      (*vec)[i] += some_value;
    }
  }
};
```

I understand that the Worker has to lock `vec` before it write to it and unlock it when it's done (because all Workers write to the same vector). But how do I express that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a boost::mutex to protect the vector, and you can use a boost::mutex::scoped_lock that'll lock the mutex in its constructor, and unlock it in the destructor

Keep in mind you need to use that same mutex **everywhere** where you access that instance of `vec` , be it reads or writes.

To get you going, you could do something like:

```
struct Worker {
  boost::mutex &vec_mutex;

  Worker(std::vector<double>* v,boost::mutex &v_mutex) : vec(v),vec_mutex(v_mutex) {}
  void operator() {        
    // do some long computation and then add results to *vec, e.g.

    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(vec_mutex);
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < vec->size(); ++i) {
      (*vec)[i] += some_value;
    }
  }

};
```

For more advanced stuff, you should encapsulate the vector and mutex further, or sooner or later you'll forget that these needs to be connected and you'll access `vec` somewhere without holding the lock leading to very hard to debug problems. For problems such as this example, I'd rather have the workers use their own individual vectors , and combine the result in the a controlling thread when the workers are done.

Comment: Did you mean `vec_mutex` instead of `io_mutex`?

Answer (score 0):

OT but useful info I hope - since you are updating this vector a lot (or just for best practice) consider [iterators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28f7db1d(v=VS.90).aspx) to iterate over the vector elements.  Making the worker code faster by not requiring use of `vector<double>::operator[]` will reduce the aggregate wait time of your worker threads.

```
for(std::vector<double>::iterator iter = vec->begin(); iter != vec->end(); ++iter) {
  *iter += some_value;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is faster? Ay prooflinks?

Comment: Iterator reduces to pointer increment.  The index requires repeated pointer dereference (to get to the vector through the local variable `vec`) and then multiplication to resolve `operator[]`.  A good optimizing compiler may be able to collapse them to the same thing but why take that chance?  Suggest you code up both and compare the assembly code that results on your particular compiler.